# how to retrieve data from mysql to jsp using spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

This is my DAO code

```
 public List<UserBean> getdata(UserBean userBean) 
        {
            return this.jdbcTemplate.query("select username from customer", new RowMapper<UserBean>() {

                public UserBean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException 
                {
                    UserBean ub = new UserBean();
                    ub.setUsername(rs.getString(1));

                    return ub;
                }

            });
        }
```

This is my controller code

```
 if(retrieveService.getdata(userBean) != null)
 { 
List<UserBean> list=retrieveService.getdata(userBean);
 return new ModelAndView("welcomes", "list", list); 
}
```

This is my jsp code

```
<ul id="myUL">
 <c:forEach var="userBean" items="${list}">   
<li><a href="#">${userBean.username}</a></li>
</c:forEach>  
</ul>
```

Actually, it executes but the last record only display in JSP

This is my MySQL record

```
 username
    james
    smith
    william
    candy

    Now output comes 
    username
    candy
    candy
    candy
    candy
Anyone correct my code
```

Comment: Inside your `mapRow` method you should be creating a new `UserBean` and return that. Now it looks like you are reusing the one passed into the method.

Comment: Where's `ub` object you are using? display your code

Comment: No need to pass bean to DAO. `${userBean.getUsername()}` Use getters to read data.

Comment: yeah, It's working dude ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAO code....

```
public List<UserBean> getdata()  {
List<UserBean> users = null;

    users = jdbcTemplate.query("select username from customer", new ResultSetExtractor<List<UserBean>>() {

        @Override
        public List<UserBean> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            List<String> usersTemp = new ArrayList<>();
            while(rs.next()) {
                UserBean ub = new UserBean();
                ub.setUsername(rs.getString(1));
                usersTemp.add(ub);
            }
            return usersTemp;
        }
    });
    return users;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You got a problem in method getData. Please refer to this code:

```
public List<Tenant> findAll() {

        List<Tenant> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT id, name, email, created_date FROM tenant",
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Tenant(rs.getInt("id"),
                        rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getDate("created_date"))
        );

        return result;

    }
```

I found it from the tutorial [Spring Boot Jdbc Mysql Example](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-jdbc-mysql-example.html)

Hope this help.